# At which point does a game count towards my stats?

Tags: overwatch

Let's say my career best in eliminations is 20. Then I play a game from the start and I do 21 eliminations, but I disconnect before VICTORY/DEFEAT appears. Will my career best now be 20 or 21? Will my averages change? What about if I disconnect after VICTORY/DEFEAT, but before the stats appear?

At what point exactly do my stats get modified?

Comment: A small note for the sake of completeness: Strictly speaking, a game will count for your Leaver stats as soon as you've gotten past character selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as the timer ends, so when the slow down starts and the Victory/Defeat message appears.

Source : if you're about to get a level, as soon as the game ends, if you pause, you should be able to see the "Open Loot Box" option.

Comment: That just shows you get experience after the Victory/Defeat message appears. What about stats like personal records and averages?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any concrete evidence of this, but since the Leaver, Experience, and Achievement systems count a game as complete as soon as Victory or Defeat appears, I'm guessing that's also when your stats will be updated.

The flip side of this is that Blizzard is trying to encourage players to stay until the end of a match, so chances are your stats won't update prior to that.